# Writing terminator character (i.e. ox1e) fails after first write

Tags: go

I have some data (MARC record actually) that I'm trying to create using go (version 1.9.2) and I can't figure out how to get the delimiting characters written to the output file.

The snippet below is an example of the closest that I've been able to come up with. The first item gets written with the appropriate terminator but nothing else after that.

What is the best/correct way to write these kinds of terminator characters in go?

```
const fieldTerminator = 0x1e

func main() {
    data := []string{"item one", "item two", "item tre"}

    writer, err := os.Create("x.out")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Could not open file: %q\n", err)
    }
    defer writer.Close() // per biosckon

    ft := make([]byte, 2)
    binary.LittleEndian.PutUint16(ft, uint16(fieldTerminator))

    for _, d := range data {
        // this just proves to me that the loop is working
        //os.Stderr.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("d is %q\n", d))
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "d is %q\n", d) // per Andy Schweig

        _, err := writer.Write([]byte(d))
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("%q\n", err)
        }

        // This prints the correct character at the end of the first item
        // and nothing after that (items 2 and 3 not printed, no errors):
        _, err = writer.Write(ft)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("%q\n", err)
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** updated code snippet to address suggestions by Andy Schweig and biosckon.

Comment: It works for me. Are you sure those bytes aren't in the file?

Comment: @andy-schweig Gah! `hexdump x.out` does indeed show them (yet my "trusty" editor doesn't). So, being new to go, is my approach considered to be the correct way to do something like this?

Comment: Yeah, it looks OK to me. That `os.Stderr.WriteString` call would be better written as `fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "d is %q\n", d)`.

Comment: @andy-schweig Thanks. So much to learn. Curious that things aren't displaying properly but that is a different issue a.t.m.

Comment: @gsiems and `defer writer.Close()` right after `Create()` and the if check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with how binary.LittleEndian.PutUint16 was being used.

What is required is a single byte for the field terminator. The result of PutUint16 is two bytes, the terminator byte and a null byte (PutUint16 doesn't work if `ft` is defined as one byte and there is no PutUint8). So the fix is to truncate `ft` after the fact to remove the null byte.

The following works as required:

```
const fieldTerminator = 0x1e

func main() {
    data := []string{"item one", "item two", "item tre"}

    writer, err := os.Create("x.out")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Could not open file: %q\n", err)
    }
    defer writer.Close()

    ft := make([]byte, 2)
    binary.LittleEndian.PutUint16(ft, uint16(fieldTerminator))
    ft = ft[:1] // Truncate ft to a single byte

    for _, d := range data {
        _, err := writer.Write([]byte(d))
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("%q\n", err)
        }

        _, err = writer.Write(ft)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("%q\n", err)
        }
    }
}
```